# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (update with subselect - joining strings)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I've checked step by step if my selects are OK- they are. I have problem with update that joins the selected results with strings:

```
select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id=428;
```

### OM_ID

```
  1507


select jni from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu =
 (select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id=428);
```

### JNI

01025180

```
update kom_prot_kontrole set nazwa_pliku = 
 (select jni from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu = 
   (select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole 
    where master_id=428)) || '_1_' || '2005' || '.pdf';




update kom_prot_kontrole set nazwa_pliku =
  (select jni from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu =
    (select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id=428)) || '_1_' || '2005' || '.pdf';

                                                                         *
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Which query is the problem maker?

Comment: Without more information we can't help you, so please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way?

```
update kom_prot_kontrole set nazwa_pliku =
  (select jni || '_1_' || '2005' from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu =
    (select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id=428))
```

**Edit:**

When you only need to update the row matching `master_id=428` you need to add another `where`, like this:

```
update kom_prot_kontrole set nazwa_pliku =
  (select jni || '_1_' || '2005' from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu =
    (select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id=428))
where master_id=428
```

Comment: what was the issue with his query?

Comment: It works but updates all of rows instead of only one.

Comment: @user3382724: That is because you miss a `where` clause.

Comment: Of course! Thank You very much! It should look like this:


update kom_prot_kontrole set nazwa_pliku =
  (select jni || '_1_' || '2005' || '.pdf' from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu =
    (select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id=428)) where master_id=428;

Answer (score -1):

|| '*1*' || '2005' seems to be acting as an alias but I don't believe one can have alias there in an update statement. Remove that and it should work..I hope.

Comment: The same error. Finally the update should gave file name. I've just forget to copy it to the code:

Comment: update kom_prot_kontrole set nazwa_pliku = ( select jni from ob_mostowe where id_obiektu = ( select distinct om_id from kom_kontrole where master_id = 428 ) ) || '_1_' || '2005' || '.pdf';

Comment: Appears the same issue to me. You have a relational statement with no use of a file name there. SQL is rightly throwing it out with the correct error. Sorry if i've misunderstood.

Comment: @MrTea: please remove your answer since it is incorrect.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I'd say both answers were correct. The filename didn't belong there. That was causing the error stated in the original question.